# BundleConfig.cs must be added in the Empty mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In this Above image Json is not loaded when i add bundleconfig.cs in my Existing project.i am using visual studio 2013 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y69lW.png)

Comment: can you please put an example i.e what are you missing

Comment: Please Answer me this question

Comment: i have added installed the web optimisation and i removed the <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly> this file from my project json is not working in my project

Comment: Can you check the console for chrome? what it shows